# What does .text.unlikely mean in ELF object files?

Tags: symbols, elf, objdump, object-files, likely-unlikely

In my `objdump -t` output, I see the following two lines:

```
00000000000004d2 l     F .text.unlikely 00000000000000ec function-signature-goes-here [clone .cold.427]
```

and

```
00000000000018e0 g     F .text  0000000000000690 function-signature-goes-here
```

I know `l` means local and `g` means global. I also know that `.text` is a section, or a type of section, in an object file, containing compiled program instructions. But what is `.text.unlikely`? Assuming it's a different section (or type-of-section) from `.text` - what's the difference?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my GCC v5.4.0 manpage, I found the following switch:

`-freorder-functions`
which says:

> Reorder functions in the object file in order to improve code
>   locality.  This is implemented by using special subsections
>   ".text.hot" for most frequently executed functions and
>   ".text.unlikely" for unlikely executed functions.  Reordering is done
>   by the linker so object file format must support named sections and
>   linker must place them in a reasonable way.
>
> Also profile feedback must be available to make this option effective.
>   See -fprofile-arcs for details.
>
> Enabled at levels -O2, -O3, -Os.

Looks like the compiler was run with optimization flags or that switch for this binary, and functions are organized in subsections to optimize spatial locality.